# Reset/Restart Flow in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio

At the end of my flow I have an option enabled to restart the flow, with this I can return to the beginning of my flow, but I have not been able to reset the variables.
Help...

Is there an alternative using serveless function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways how you can achieve this result:

## Pointing back to the beginning of the flow via a **transition**

This way, the flow would just start again. Please note that you need to reset all used variables with the "Set Variables" widget

## Exiting the flow and re-entering via the Rest API trigger

For this, you need to define a Serverless function that triggers a new flow via the Rest API of your flow. Please keep in mind that you have to point both triggers to your initial widget then. The variables will be reset automatically, as this is a new execution.